# Why is my datapack timing out players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm working on a "species" datapack, which includes a species meant to emulate spiders. One of the abilities of this spiders species is that they move more swiftly through cobwebs.

How I'm currently achieving this is by assigning an attribute modifier for movement speed: `execute as @a[scores={Species=007},tag=species007-01,tag=!CobwebSpeed] run attribute @s minecraft:generic.movement_speed modifier add 679b313e-ab32-4969-a166-213e61c2ea75 "MovementSpeed" 8 multiply_base`.

The CobwebSpeed tag is assigned if this statement is true, so that the attribute modifier isn't re-applied every tick, to cut down on lag.

The species007-01 tag is assigned by a separate function if the player standing in a cobweb. This is achieved by testing at the player's feet, as well as 0.3 blocks in all eight cardinal directions of them, for a cobweb. I don't believe this is the issue, as this function is run every tick, and lag only occurs only when the player enters a cobweb. I can provide the code of this function as well, if needed.

Below is the four lines of code I use to apply and remove the attribute modifier. Again, having the tag `species007-01` means the player is currently inside a cobweb.

```
execute as @a[scores={Species=007},tag=!species007-01] run attribute @s minecraft:generic.movement_speed modifier remove 679b313e-ab32-4969-a166-213e61c2ea75
tag @a[scores={Species=007},tag=CobwebSpeed,tag=!species007-01] remove CobwebSpeed
execute as @a[scores={Species=007},tag=species007-01,tag=!CobwebSpeed] run attribute @s minecraft:generic.movement_speed modifier add 679b313e-ab32-4969-a166-213e61c2ea75 "MovementSpeed" 8 multiply_base
tag @a[scores={Species=007},tag=!CobwebSpeed,tag=species007-01] add CobwebSpeed
```

The issue is that, on the server where I use this datapack, whenever a player with the spider species steps inside a datapack, their PC seems to immediately stop communicating with the server. The attribute is not removed, and they cannot interact with the world around them. They also freeze on the screens of the other players.

However, I was able to escape this "frozen" state by manually breaking the cobweb where the server still thought I was. When I did that, the server caught up, and I was able to play normally again. However, I wasn't able to place or break any other blocks in this state.

**Here's my actual question:** Has anyone experienced this before? Does anyone have ANY idea what could be causing this?

Comment: "Has anyone experienced this before?" isn't an actual question, but "Why does this happen and how do I fix this?" is one.

Comment: This is not a request for technical support for modded Minecraft - the data pack mentioned is the one the user has a problem with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the commands you've provided. Could you upload the entire datapack to a file sharing site and provide the link?

Comment: @LostXOR Yes, thank you. It's the zip file called "SSE" in the provided Google Drive.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1e1uyg_qf3_PcPpOHBPGyRfQT8lBk6OXc?usp=drive_link